# Your file exceeds the maximum upload size for this site: 64MB. When I upload my website local host to live server shows to me

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, hosting, space

My **domain** and **hosting** site is https://www.pk-domain.com/
Theme is *Zakra* and Editor is *Elementor*.
Can you help me for *Increase the maximum space* my site file is more than 200MB.

[***Screen Shot***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIgoA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact your hosting provider or you need to install [All-in-One WP migration import plugi](https://import.wp-migration.com/)n, that increase file size to 512 Mb.

Answer (score 0):

There are different way to increase your maximum upload size

**Contact Your Hosting Provider**
This is the easiest solution as you don't mesh your configuration

and some of alternative solutions can be used if your hosting provider takes too much time to respond

**.htaccess’ File**

Open the .htaccess file and then add the following lines

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

**Create or Modify the ‘php.ini’**

Usually this php.ini is located in your root folder if it doesn't exist then you can create this files manually and add the following lines

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
memory_limit = 128M
```

**Using Wordpress Plugin**

If you are not comfortable with the file editing stuff then you can use this plugin which is available in WordPress repository [WP Increase Upload Filesize | Increase Maximum Execution Time](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maximum-upload-file-size/)

**Verification**

You can verify/confirm the changes by Site Health Info which is available in WordPress

Comment: Thanks for Everything and help.